# What are the reasons to receive "Serving Limit Exceeded" on Google Translate API?

Tags: translation, google-translate

Today I start getting a strange message when using the Google translate API

Error
[code] => 403
[message] => Serving Limit Exceeded

Only a few days ago the last bill (which was only $2.10) was paid automatically.
Do you have any idea what the problem is? Or what I should do?

I am far from overcoming the daily limit. Does this happen to anyone else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, my account is well under quota.

There's quite a few more people with the same problem, a few people have posted on the Google Translate discussion board: http://groups.google.com/group/google-translate-general/browse_thread/thread/ff176c95cad04c90#

Hopefully it'll get sorted out soon.